# File handling function call error

Tags: c

I have found a problem from the text book Let us C by Yeshavant Kanethkar. The question is that you have to find the error in following program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void openfile(char *, FILE **);
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    openfile( "Myfile",fp);
    if(fp==NULL)
        printf("Unable to open file...\n");
    return 0;
}
void openfile(char *fn, FILE **f)
{
    *f=fopen(fn,"r");
}
```

And the answer given is "No error", but I'm not convinced because while calling file open function we should call it by reference:

```
openfile("Myfile",&fp);
```

to work with this program without error.

Is my understanding correct, or is the text book right?

Comment: What does the compiler tell you?

Comment: `openfile( "Myfile",fp);` -> `openfile( "Myfile", &fp);`. Your compiler warned you. In C certains warnings as the one you've got should be considered as errors. Which compoiler do you use ?

Comment: Hint: get rid of that book...

Comment: @LPs as far as I understood the reader should find the error in this program.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well, but _the answer given is "No error"._ is semantically correct but very wrong here...

Comment: @LPs OK, I understood the _compiler_ gave this "answer", but maybe I'm wrong, the question is poorly written.

Comment: Who pretends tha answer is "No error" ?

Comment: This program contain logical error not Syntex error. but error is error we should consider that also.

Comment: Stop reading a book by someone who couldn't even be bothered to compile their own examples. At the very least check if there is an errata to the book.

Comment: Can anyone suggest be book for c!

Comment: I am not beginner i want some advance book. thank you.

Comment: @Lundin this is an exercise in the [book](https://www.cluster2.hostgator.co.in/files/writeable/uploads/hostgator99706/file/letusc-yashwantkanetkar.pdf) where the reader is to find errors in small programs. The answers however are not provided in the book.

Comment: @Michael Walz answer is on different book written by same author and contain solution of all problem in this book. let us say that book is past of this book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expression

```
  openfile("Myfile", &fp);
```

instead of

```
  openfile("Myfile", fp);
```

makes program completed.

The problem of `openfile("Myfile", fp)` is in pointer types: if declaration is `FILE *fp;` to get type `FILE **` from `fp` you need address of pointer, and unary `&` can help.

Compiler can make compilation without error message, because both `FILE *` and `FILE **` are pointers and implicit conversion works, but usually warning is shown for such cases.

My Visual Studio's warning looks like:

> Warning  1   warning C4047: 'function' : 'FILE **' differs in levels of indirection from 'FILE *'    c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapp\source.c 10

**UPDATE:**

Try the following updated program:

```cpp
#include<stdio.h>
void openfile(char *, FILE **);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    printf("Before:\n");
    printf("value of fp = %p\n", fp);
    printf("address of fp = %p\n", &fp);
    openfile("Myfile", &fp);
    printf("After:\n");
    printf("value of fp = %p\n", fp);
    printf("address of fp = %p\n", &fp);
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Unable to open file...\n");
    return 0;
}

void openfile(char *fn, FILE **f)
{
    printf("Inside (before):\n");
    printf("value of f = %p\n", f);
    printf("value of *f = %p\n", *f);
    *f = fopen(fn, "r");
    printf("Inside (after):\n");
    printf("value of f = %p\n", f);
    printf("value of *f = %p\n", *f);
}
```

If your program can open file, you will see something like

```
Before:
value of fp = 00000000
address of fp = 0019F9B0
Inside (before):
value of f = 0019F9B0
value of *f = 00000000
Inside (after):
value of f = 0019F9B0
value of *f = 580E7350
After:
value of fp = 580E7350
address of fp = 0019F9B0
```

Here we see addresses, and that value of `fp` was changed after call of openfile

Comment: yeah! thats what. means answer is wrong in the book.

Comment: What can I say....Books are imperfect because have been written by imperfect human beings. Perhaps, there is a mistype in the book.

Comment: or what is the  meaning of following statement.                                                                            FILE fp;

Comment: FILE is a structure containing data required to system functions to work with file. Do not try to change value fields in it

Comment: can we explore all library like stdio.h or stdlib.h  code by code so that we understand its deepest nature??

Comment: Of course you can find fields (they are `_ptr`, `_base`, `_bufsiz`, `_charbuf`, etc.) and read about their purpose, but you should understand that content of `FILE` should be changed only by functions of standard library